# Does Latin "pingo" relate to "pix"?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, proto-indo-european

Does Latin "pingo" to paint relate to "pix" tar by analogy with  "pango" to agree and "pax" peace?

Comment: Question by yet another sock puppet of suspended user.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: *I'm not even close to expert in Proto-Indo-European, so maybe I'm missing something important*.

**Apparently not.**

According to [this](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?root=config&morpho=0) database:

- [pingo](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=germ%2Bbalt%2Bslav%2Bgreek%2Biran%2Bavest%2Bind%2Btokh%2Bhitt%2Bmeaning%2Bproto%2Bprnum%2Barm%2Bital%2Bcelt%2Balb%2Brusmean%2Brefer%2Bcomment&text_proto=&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_hitt=&method_hitt=substring&ic_hitt=on&text_tokh=&method_tokh=substring&ic_tokh=on&text_ind=&method_ind=substring&ic_ind=on&text_avest=&method_avest=substring&ic_avest=on&text_iran=&method_iran=substring&ic_iran=on&text_arm=&method_arm=substring&ic_arm=on&text_greek=&method_greek=substring&ic_greek=on&text_slav=&method_slav=substring&ic_slav=on&text_balt=&method_balt=substring&ic_balt=on&text_germ=&method_germ=substring&ic_germ=on&text_lat=ping%C5%8D&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&text_ital=&method_ital=substring&ic_ital=on&text_celt=&method_celt=substring&ic_celt=on&text_alb=&method_alb=substring&ic_alb=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_refer=&method_refer=substring&ic_refer=on&text_comment=&method_comment=substring&ic_comment=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on) comes from PIE root *peik'-
- [pix](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cpiet&first=1&off=&text_proto=&method_proto=substring&ic_proto=on&text_meaning=&method_meaning=substring&ic_meaning=on&text_hitt=&method_hitt=substring&ic_hitt=on&text_tokh=&method_tokh=substring&ic_tokh=on&text_ind=&method_ind=substring&ic_ind=on&text_avest=&method_avest=substring&ic_avest=on&text_iran=&method_iran=substring&ic_iran=on&text_arm=&method_arm=substring&ic_arm=on&text_greek=&method_greek=substring&ic_greek=on&text_slav=&method_slav=substring&ic_slav=on&text_balt=&method_balt=substring&ic_balt=on&text_germ=&method_germ=substring&ic_germ=on&text_lat=pix&method_lat=substring&ic_lat=on&text_ital=&method_ital=substring&ic_ital=on&text_celt=&method_celt=substring&ic_celt=on&text_alb=&method_alb=substring&ic_alb=on&text_rusmean=&method_rusmean=substring&ic_rusmean=on&text_refer=&method_refer=substring&ic_refer=on&text_comment=&method_comment=substring&ic_comment=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=proto&ic_any=on) comes from PIE root *pik-

The source, according to the site is:

> Walde-Pokorny's dictionary [possibly the [Indogermanisches etymologisches Wörterbuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indogermanisches_etymologisches_W%C3%B6rterbuch)], compiled by S. L. Nikolayev

... which is a pity, because it was fun to think that the verb *to paint* and *pitch/tar* were etymologically related in Latin. (and makes *some* sense).

Comment: Right. A connection is ruled by the Balto-Slavic forms, which show a sibilant in the "paint" word and velar in the "pitch" word; this means the former had a palatovelar in PIE, the latter a plain velar.